# Dedup data frame without using unique()

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to get the row number per group in a grouped data frame. This seems to work as needed:

Some data:

```
library(dplyr)

my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('Car') %>% 
  
  # add some duplicate rows
  add_row(.[3,]) %>% 
  add_row(.[7,]) %>% 
  add_row(.[10,]) %>% 
  group_by(Car) %>% 
  mutate(n = n(),
         rn = row_number())

my_mtcars %>% arrange(desc(n), Car) %>% View
```

[image]

This seems to get me what I need, row_number() per group. However, I need to pass a chr vect to group by as opposed to the field names. If I change my group_by line to `group_by(vars(c('Car')))` the row numbers are no longer per group but for the df as a whole.

[image]

How can I get row_number() per group while passing a chr string to group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
string <- 'Car'

group_by(.data[[string]])
```

Or with `across` :

```
group_by(across(all_of(string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also convert to `sym`bol and evaluate with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
string1 <- "Car"
group_by(!! rlang::sym(string1))
```